# how to add file name to converted byte file

Tags: java

I am downloading the generated ics calendar, while downloading the ics calendar it is downloading name like a "ics". I am trying to add name like "test.ics", But i am not able to add the name. please help me to add name dynamically to the downloaded the ics file. Using below code to convert ics file to bytes.

```
private byte[] calendarAsByteArray(net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar calendar) throws FileNotFoundException {
    byte[] bytes;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream output =  new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
        outputter.setValidating(false);
        outputter.output(calendar, output);
        bytes = output.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't convert calendar to bytes: "+e);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: I don't unterstand the relation between your code and your question. You convert an Calendar to a Byte-Array. Such a primitive type has nothing to do with filenames and your code doesn't even write your calendar to a file.

Comment: When saving a file it is saving like "ics". But I want to add name like "test.ics"

Answer (score 0):

You can write your bytes array to file and specify filename you want:

```
    private byte[] calendarAsByteArray(net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar calendar) throws FileNotFoundException {
        byte[] bytes;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream output =  new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            CalendarOutputter outputter = new CalendarOutputter();
            outputter.setValidating(false);
            outputter.output(calendar, output);
            bytes = output.toByteArray();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.ics");
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.close()

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("can't convert calendar to bytes: "+e);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: When saving a file it is saving like "ics". But I want to add name like "test.ics

Comment: You did not provided code where it is saved to file like "ics". What you showed is only calendar converted to byte array. So in my answer I write your bytes to file with explicitly stated name "test.ics"

Comment: For this ics file download, I am providing download link. when even we click the download link the ics file will be downloaded to our local system. ics calendar already converted into bytes. after converting only we downloaded.

Comment: Are you downloading your file in your Java program, or clicking on link in browser?

Comment: clicking on download link, the download link will call the service"http://localhost:8080/test/api/v1/test123/ics"